# React - MUI InputBase loses focus on each keypress

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have run into a bug with a custom component which I implemented for search functionality where on each keypress custom input component loses the focus. Can someone help me with a solution to avoid this behaviour.

## Search component

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { InputBase } from "@mui/material";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";

export const SearchInput = (props) => {
  const Search = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    position: "relative",
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(171, 171, 171, 0.15)",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(171, 171, 171, 0.25)",
    },
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "46.67px",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "auto",
    },
  }));

  const SearchIconWrapper = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
    height: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    pointerEvents: "none",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  }));

  const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
    color: "inherit",
    "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
      padding: "12px 8px 12px 0px",
      // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
      paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
      transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
      width: "100%",
      [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        width: "12ch",
        "&:focus": {
          width: "20ch",
        },
      },
    },
  }));

  return (
    <Search>
      <SearchIconWrapper>
        <SearchIcon />
      </SearchIconWrapper>
      <StyledInputBase
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search", type: "text" }}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        value={props.value}
      />
    </Search>
  );
};
```

```
  // search functionality
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const types = [];

    Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => {
      if (params[key]) {
        types.push(key.toLowerCase());
      }
    });

    if (types.length === 0) {
      Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => types.push(key.toLowerCase()));
    }

    if (!searchInput || searchInput === "") {
      setFilteredResults(sportItems);
    } else {
      const filteredObjects = {};

      Object.keys(sportItems).forEach((key) => {
        const filteredItems = [];
        const items = sportItems[key];

        items.forEach((item) => {
          let canInclued = false;
          types.forEach((type) => {
            if (
              item[type] &&
              item[type].name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput)
            ) {
              canInclued = true;
            }
          });

          if (canInclued) {
            filteredItems.push(item);
          }
        });

        if (filteredItems.length > 0) {
          filteredObjects[key] = filteredItems;
        }
      });

      setFilteredResults(filteredObjects);
    }
  }, [params, sportItems, searchInput]);
```

```
<Box>
  {priceBookStep !== "add-price-book-entry" && (
    <Grid container gap={"16px"} alignItems={"center"} textAlign="left">
      <Box>
        <Box sx={{ fontSize: 12, color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)" }}>
          Filter results by
        </Box>
        <Box className={classes.checkBoxContainer}>
          {Object.keys(params).map((key) => (
            <FormControlLabel
              key={key}
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  checked={params[key].checked}
                  onChange={(e) => handleFilterParam(key)}
                />
              }
              label={key.replace(/_/g, " ")}
            />
          ))}
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <SearchInput
        placeholder="Search Entry"
        onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
        value={searchInput}
      />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        className={classes.headerButton}
        onClick={() => handlePriceBookEntry("new")}
      >
        <AddCircleOutline />
        add new Price book entry
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  )}
</Box>
```

I tried to make a custom input component for search functinality and use it in my app. But when I try to type something in the text input it loses the focus on each keypress. But when I implement the component in the same file without diving it to a separate component it works.

Answer (score 1):

> MUI InputBase loses focus on each keypress

It loses it's focus since the components are being re-created with every component re-render. And since the `value` of the input comes with props, with every prop change after each key stroke it loses focus. You should move them outside the `SearchInput` component.